# Stuck with: 'Uncaught TypeError: this.state.users.map is not a function' in react (Axios)

Tags: reactjs, api, dictionary, get, axios

I want to make a get request to this dummy endpoint: https://reqres.in/api/users/2

but I constantly get the error message:

```
TypeError: this.state.users.map is not a function
```

This is my code:

```
state = {
 users: []
}

componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`https://reqres.in/api/users/2`)
        .then(res => {

            this.setState({ users : res.data });
        })
}
```

Any help on what I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the endpoint is returning an object not an array.

If you wish to use an array you could do this:

`this.setState({ users: [res.data] })`

But in a nutshell I personally would change this name of state to a singular term. Then  use it as an object (as it from the endpoint).

E.g

`this.setState({ person: res.data })`

Then consume properties as desired:

`this.state.person.id`

Hope this helps